# AnyLogic inject agents from existing population with characteristics

Tags: anylogic, inject

I created a population with objects from a database with individual characteristics.
[image: my population]

I am trying that the objects with a specific value are injected into a source for process-modelling.
("ankunftszeit" means "arrival time")

```
for (mp_lkw l : pop_mp_lkw){
if (l.ankunftszeit == getTime()){
source_mp_lkw.inject(mp_lkw l, 1, false, false);
}
}
```

But somehow an Error occurs and I cannot find any solution...
It says taht the inject() only accepts integers

The method inject(int) in the type Source<mp_lkw> is not applicable for the arguments (mp_lkw, int, boolean, boolean)
Syntax error on token "l", delete this token

Where is my mistake and how can it be corrected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand your issue, but if the agents already exist, you shouldn't use a source, instead use an enter block, and then change your code to (even though this code seems like a terrible idea... instead you should use dynamic events but I'm not sure your purpose)

```
for (mp_lkw l : pop_mp_lkw){
   if (l.ankunftszeit == getTime()){
      enter.take(l);
    }
}
```